# Matplotlib clip_on = False does not work on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I set `clip_on = False` the curve extends beyond the y-limits, but it does not extend beyond the x-limits.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

For example, the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x1 = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
y1 = x1
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.plot(x1, y1, clip_on = False)
```

produces the plot I would expect:

[image: good]

However, all I have to do is change the y-limits,

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-3,3)
ax.plot(x1, y1, clip_on = False)
```

and I get the following plot:

[image: bad]

Why does the first plot extend beyond the y-limits, while the second one does not extend beyond the x-limits?  In case it matters, I am using matplotlib 1.3.0 with the TkAgg backend.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with matplotlib 1.3 and the MacOSX backend.

Comment: I just added posted this problem as Issue # 2675 on the Matplotlib Github repository webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work by limiting the number of data points to be less than 100 with the current version of matplotlib (e.g. `x1 = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.5)` in the example you gave) or by setting markevery (even if you do not have markers) as one of the plot options, i.e., `ax.plot(x1, y1, clip_on = False, markevery=1)`.

Comment: As a note for others that find this, please see cimarron's post on my Issue # 2675 on the Matplotlib Github website.  He supplies a bit more detail there.  Thank you for the work around, cimarron.  I have accepted your answer, since I doubt that there will be anything better until some changes are made to matplotlib.